# Glide typing for custom keyboard

Tags: android, slide, custom-keyboard, android-input-method

I am creating a custom keyboard which rearranges the keys such that glide typing (like Swype) becomes more accurate and is less stressful for a one-hand user. So far, I created a keyboard prototype with moving keys (see link below), but I could not find an easy way to include glide typing. Do you know if there is a library which I could use?

https://github.com/Rodonex/Custom-Keyboard-Layout/raw/master/promo.gif

I tried to built the glide sliding function myself but this seems like a lot of effort.